# JS скидки при изменении количества площади

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть такая вот задачка:
Есть небольшой калькулятор, где есть 4 поля:
Тип ремонта (радио кнопки), площадь помещения, цена и цена со скидкой.
Просчет цены производится на ура, а вот просчитать ценник со скидкой, в зависимости от площади, ни как не могу запустить.
Зависимость идет следующая: площадь от 30 до 50 м - скидка 5%, от 50 до 70 - 7%, от 70 до 100м - 15%, более 100м - 20%
Вот такой вот скрипт использую:

```js
$('#js-amount-range, .checkbox-checkbox').bind('input', calcAndShow);

function calcAndShow() {
  var v1 = parseFloat($("#js-amount-range").val());
  var v2 = parseFloat($('input[name="select3"]:checked').val());
  var text, text2, summa;
  text = v1 * v2 * 20;
  text2 = '<span>руб</span>';
  summa = text + ' ' + text2;

  $('div#mainresult').html(summa);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calc__row"><span class="calc__label">Тип ремонта</span>
  <div class="calc__types">
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-1" type="radio" name="select3" value="10" checked="" /><label for="calc__radio3-1">черновой</label></div>
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-2" type="radio" name="select3" value="20" /><label for="calc__radio3-2">косметический</label></div>
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-3" type="radio" name="select3" value="30" /><label for="calc__radio3-3">капитальный</label></div>
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-4" type="radio" name="select3" value="40" /><label for="calc__radio3-4">дизайнерский</label></div>
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-5" type="radio" name="select3" value="50" /><label for="calc__radio3-5">в ванной</label></div>
    <div class="calc__radio"><input class="checkbox-checkbox" id="calc__radio3-6" type="radio" name="select3" value="60" /><label for="calc__radio3-6">в кухне</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="range-slider"><span class="range__title">Площадь квартиры</span><input id="js-amount-input" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
  <div class="range-slider__row"><span class="range-span">1м<sup>2</sup></span><input class="range" id="js-amount-range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="180" /><span class="range-span">180м<sup>2</sup></span></div>
</div>
<div class="calc__price">
  <div class="calc__price_title">Примерная стоимость вашего ремонта:</div>
  <div class="calc__price_sum" id="mainresult"><span>руб</span></div>
</div>
<div class="calc__dial">
  <div class="calc__dial_title">С учетом специальной скидки:</div>
  <div class="calc__dial_sum" id="skidka">19 000<span>руб</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

За такие названия переменных коллеги Вас будут бить.

```
var fullprice = text;
var discounted = fullprice;
if (v1 >= 30 && v1 < 50)
  discounted = fullprice * 0.95;
else if (v1 >= 50 && v1 < 70)
  discounted = fullprice * 0.93;
else if (v1 >= 70 && v1 < 100)
  discounted = fullprice * 0.85;
else if (v1 >= 100)
  discounted = fullprice * 0.80;

$("#skidka").html(discounted + " <span>руб</span>");
```